# Anaconda - How can I update all packages of another environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, package

I have Anaconda (of Python 3.5)/

```
conda update --all
```

command updates all the packages of default Python 3.5

I also have installed another environment of Python 2.7. The above command updates only the 'base' environment for Python 3.5.
How can I update all packages of Python 2.7 environment?

Answer (score 8):

Use the `-n` or `--name` flag:

```
conda update -n env-name --all
```

or activate the environment, then run the update command